# Php/MySQL - array_push from two arrays

Tags: php, mysql

Below I create 2 arrays:

```
$album_permissions = array();
$result1 = mysql_query("select w_group from albums_permissions where id='$album'") or die('Error1');
while(list($w_group) = mysql_fetch_row($result1)) {
$album_permissions[] = $w_group;
}

$photoids = array();
$result2 = mysql_query("select id from photos where album='$album'") or die('Error2x');
while(list($photo_id) = mysql_fetch_row($result2)) {
$photoids[] = $photo_id;
}
```

The result will be something like this:

```
$album_permissions = array('2', '8', '20');
```

and

```
$photoids = array('4', '5', '7', '9');
```

I need to insert into DB all permissions from `$album_permissions` for each of `$photoids`.

I need the following result:

```
$values = array();

array_push($values, "('4','2','$user_id','$timestamp')");
array_push($values, "('4','8','$user_id','$timestamp')");
array_push($values, "('4','20','$user_id','$timestamp')");

array_push($values, "('5','2','$user_id','$timestamp')");
array_push($values, "('5','8','$user_id','$timestamp')");
array_push($values, "('5','20','$user_id','$timestamp')");

array_push($values, "('7','2','$user_id','$timestamp')");
array_push($values, "('7','8','$user_id','$timestamp')");
array_push($values, "('7','20','$user_id','$timestamp')");

array_push($values, "('9','2','$user_id','$timestamp')");
array_push($values, "('9','8','$user_id','$timestamp')");
array_push($values, "('9','20','$user_id','$timestamp')");


$result1 = mysql_query("insert INTO photos_permissions(photoid,w_group,user,timestamp) VALUES ".implode(",", $values)) or die('Error3');
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to combine the data from both arrays - `$album_permissions` and `$photoids` :(

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: array_push($values, array('4','2','$user_id','$timestamp'));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$values = array();
foreach($photoids as $id)
{
    foreach($album_permissions as $album)
    {
        array_push($values, "('$id','$album','$user_id','$timestamp')");
    }
}
```

But as esqew said, it's not a good idea to use those mysql functions. I hope you only do this to understand how php/mysql works.